# Alternate Form of Correspondence Principle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

Let G be a group and K a normal subgroup in G. Let f : G → G/K be the canonical epimorphism given by x → xK and L a subgroup of G/K. Then

(1) There exists a subgroup H of G. H contains K, and L=H/K. Further, H is normal in G, if and only if L is normal in G/K. Furthermore, if G is finite, prove [G : H] =
[G/K : H/K]=[G/K :L] and |H|=|K|·|L|.

(2) Suppose that H1, H2 are two subgroups of G and H1, H2 contain K. If H1/K=H2/K, then H1=H2.

I find this one quite different from the original form of Correspondence Principle, which is a lot easier to understand and to proof. I know I have to use the isomorphism theorems to prove this one, but can anyone give a sketch or a hint? Thanks!

Comment: You have to tell us what's your verion of the correspondence Theorem as what you wrote in (1) is the version I know, albeit slightly messier. (2) follows at once from this.

Comment: original form is http://www.math.ucla.edu/~rse/algebra_book.pdf    
theorem 13.2, page 74

Comment: For me, the CT is 13.3, which is what you wrote. Theorem 13.2, which for some reason is called "principle" by the author, is just some a list of nice, though basic, properties of epimorphisms.

Comment: which book are you referring to, for your CT? any ideas of how to prove them...a bit abstract for me

Comment: You can google it, or for example the book in group theory by Rotman has it by that name.

Answer (score 1):

Ideas for demonstration:

We have $\;K\lhd G\;$ and the quotient $\;G/K\;$. Say $\;\overline L\le G/K\;$ , and define

$$L:=\left\{g\in G\;:\;\;gK\in\overline L\right\}$$

(1) Prove that $\;L\;$ is a subgroup of G containing $\;K\;$

(2) Prove that $\;\overline L\lhd G/K\iff L\lhd G\;$

(3) Prove that $\;[G/K : \overline L]=[G:L]\;$

Now, show that if $\; T\le G\;$ contains $\;K\;$ , then

$$\overline T:=\left\{ gK\in G/K\;:\;\;g\in T\right\}$$

is a subgroup of $\;G/K\;$ .

Finally, show that both correspondences  above: $\;\overline L\to L\;,\;\;T\to\overline T\;$ are inverse to each other, and this fact is precisely what allows us to write any subgroup of $\;G/K\;$ in the form $\;L/K\;$ , with $\;K\le L\le G\;$